# Upload file in another domain

Tags: php, api, mp3

i have form that provides upload mp3 and give .mp3 link

```
<form action="https://upload.clyp.it/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="audioFile">
    <input type="submit" value="Send to Clyp">
</form>
```

api link: https://clyp.it/api

i want to insert this form in my website, upload mp3 and then save link in my database. problem is that after upload it redirects.
i tried ajax upload but not works, it gives me cross origin error.
i also tried upload with curl but not works.
any idea?

Comment: The response is JSON, parse it and get the url.

Comment: how? it redirect to another domain.

Comment: The form in your website will post back to your server and then you will take the file and CUrl it to the api and then parse the response and get the url.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow cross origin on ur PHP code ... 
use this in the PHP code where you are uploading the File to.
It should Help

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```